# Immutable class using static factories

Tags: java, immutability, effective-java, static-factory

I'm studying Effective Java by Joshua Bloch, where he explains about different ways of achieving immutable class. To prevent subclassing, one way is to use *final*. The more sophisticated way for it is to make constructor private, thus preventing outside access, and using static factories for object creation.

However, I don't understand this statement:

```
public class Complex {
    private final double re;
    private final double im;

    private Complex(double re, double im) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }

    public static Complex valueOf(double re, double im) {
        return new Complex(re, im);
    }
}
```

*It is most flexible because it allows the use of multiple package-private implementation classes.*

I understand that it's not possible for an outside client to subclass it in absence of a public/protected constructor, but do not understand what is being conveyed by the term 'multiple package private implementation classes'.

NOTE: This is Item 15 (Minimize mutability) in Effective Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember Joshua then talks about [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) (but I do not remember context where he mentions it).

`EnumSet` is abstract and also has static methods [of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#of(E)), [noneOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#noneOf(java.lang.Class)), etc.
There are two classes extending `EnumSet`: `JumboEnumSet` and `RegularEnumSet`.

You cannot use them directly because they are package-private (no `public` keyword):

```
class RegularEnumSet<E extends Enum<E>> extends EnumSet<E>
class JumboEnumSet<E extends Enum<E>> extends EnumSet<E>
```

`java.util` package only can use them directly (if we do not speak about reflection or some other techinques).

You simply use static methods of `EnumSet` and it returns some subclass of `EnumSet` you should not be aware of.

Take a look at the `noneOf` method implementation:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> EnumSet<E> noneOf(Class<E> elementType) {
    Enum<?>[] universe = getUniverse(elementType);
    if (universe == null)
        throw new ClassCastException(elementType + " not an enum");

    if (universe.length <= 64)
        return new RegularEnumSet<>(elementType, universe);
    else
        return new JumboEnumSet<>(elementType, universe);
}
```

Here is the multiple package-private implementations

Comment: I agree, he mentioned so in the earlier item that he explained. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only way a class cannot be subclassed is if the class is marked as `final`. Since this class is not `final`, then **it can be subclassed**, like this:

```
public class Complex {

    private final double re;
    private final double im;

    private Complex(double re, double im) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }

    //methods...

    static class SubComplex1 extends Complex {

        private SubComplex1(double re, double im, double x) {
            super(re, im);
            //more elements...
        }
        //you can define/override methods here
    }

    public static Complex valueOf(double re, double im, double x) {
        return new SubComplex1(re, im, x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, but not sure this the point here. The solution above is mostly for API, where you will not be able to add an inner class to subclass it. It is basicly an effectively final class  (not sure this is a term for `class`...)

Comment: @AxelH who knows. You can do this like the JDK does for implementations like `Collections#asList` where it has an inner static private class, just to mention one of lots of examples.

Comment: Like I said, I agree with the code here, but you need to be able to update the class implementation, if you provide an API (not the source code), you can't add that inner class. Giving an effectively final class.

Comment: @AxelH not completely true if you don't want your client to extend your class but still want to be able for you (the API vendor) to update and extend it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Though you're right in pointing out the subclassing, in this context the author is explaining about how to prevent subclassing from a client's perspective (as he mentions so in the following lines). So, the class becomes effectively final.